# Neo4j schema indexing is very slow

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I'm trying to implement indexes in NE4OJ in order to speed up some queries.

One of the queries is to find some people based on a string using `where people.key IN [<10 string values here>]`. 
We have around 180k nodes with the label `People` in the database and the query takes 41s to return the result.

So I created a schema Index on this property, run again the query and nothing changed. By curiosity, I decided to select by ID:

```
match (people:People)
where ID(people) IN [789806,908117,934851,934857,935125,935174,935177,935183,935581,935586,935587,935588,935634,935636,935637,935638,935639]
return ID(people)
```

It took 92ms. Perfect! So I tried to create a new property called `test`, index it and set the same value as the node id. Then I run the following query:

```
match (people:People)
where people.test IN [789806,908117,934851,934857,935125,935174,935177,935183,935581,935586,935587,935588,935634,935636,935637,935638,935639]
return ID(people)
```

It took again 41s (41000ms). Am I missing something? I really don't understand... Is it some performance conf?

FYI, we use NEO4J 2.0.0 on Debian.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember the `IN` operation was not using an existing index in 2.0.x. So try to upgrade to 2.1.3 and retry.

Comment: Yes I've just figured out by reading the release note and it works :) Thanks !!